# How can I execute my code better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two pieces of code, and I think they are ugly. How can I change them?

1

```
do_withs = Dowith.where(:friend_id => current_user.id)
@doweets = do_withs.collect { |f| f.doweet_id }
@doweets = @doweets.collect { |f| Doweet.find((F)) }
@doweets = @doweets + current_user.doweets 
@doweets.flatten!
@doweets.sort! { |a,b| a.date <=> b.date }
```

2

```
@current_user_doweets = current_user.doweets.limit(10)
@friendships = Friendship.where(:friend_id => current_user.id, :status => true)
@friends = @friendships.collect { |f| User.find(f.user_id) }
@friends_doweets = @friends.collect(&:doweets)
@doweets = @current_user_doweets  + @friends_doweets
@doweets.flatten!
@doweets.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
```

models:

```
class Doweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
  has_many :dowiths
  belongs_to :user
end

class Dowith < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doweet
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doweets
  has_many :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

Comment: Could you add some more information about the relationships between your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this simplifies things a tad (but my syntax might be off...

```
@doweets = Dowith.where(:friend_id => current_user.id).collect do |d|
[
    Doweet.find(d.doweet_id)    
]
end

@doweets << current_user.doweets
@doweets.sort! do |a,b| a.date <=> b.date end
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Take advantage of your model associations to reduce the number of database queries you generate by eager-loading with the `includes` method:

```
@doweets = Dowith.where(:friend_id => current_user.id).includes(:doweet).collect(&:doweet) + current_user.doweets
@doweets.sort! {|doweet1, doweet2| doweet1.date <=> doweet2.date}
```

2) Very similar to 1:

```
@friends_doweets = Friendship.where(:friend_id => current_user.id, :status => true).includes(:user => :doweets).collect{|friendship| friendship.user.doweets}
@doweets = current_user.doweets.limit(10) + @friends_doweets
@doweets.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
```

Watch your log file to see the difference in the number of database queries that occur.  It's not a huge deal, but I think you can eliminate a lot of instance variables from your code and replace them with local variables.  Instance variables in your controller actions should be used to pass data to your views.

Comment: Note that lines like `@friends_doweets = Friendship.where(:friend_id => current_user.id, :status => true).includes(:user => :doweets).collect{|friendship| friendship.user.doweets}` are compact and efficient, but less readable than other ways of writing code to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@doweets = Dowith.where(:friend_id => current_user.id).collect &:doweet_id
@doweets = Doweet.find_all_by_id(@doweets)
@doweets = (@doweets + current_user.doweets).sort_by &:date


@current_user_doweets = current_user.doweets.limit(10)
@friendships = Friendship.where(:friend_id => current_user.id, :status => true)
@friends = User.includes(:doweets).find_all_by_id(@friendships.collect(&:user_id))
@friends_doweets = @friends.collect(&:doweets).flatten
@doweets = (@current_user_doweets + @friends_doweets).sort_by &:created_at
```